# Array internal pointer after foreach construct not showing

Tags: php

This is the relevant section of my code to this problem--
$movies is a multidimensional array with array 'Good Movies' inside of it and array 'Harry Potter' inside of 'Good Movies'.

```
foreach ($movies['Good Movies']['Harry Potter'] as $item){
echo '<Strong>Harry Potter and the </strong>';
echo '<em>'.$item.'</em><br/>';
}
echo current($movies['Good Movies']['Harry Potter']);
```

When I run it, the current() function doesn't show any error, but it doesn't echo anything. The foreach works, but the current() doesn't. If I replace the 'current' with 'reset' or 'end', then it does work. If I put the 'current()' function code line in the foreach loop then it works but displays the same result every time. Shouldn't the pointer advance as it loops through the loop?

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? Please let us know..

Comment: I want to know "current($movies['Good Movies']['Harry Potter'])". Basically, I want to know where the pointer is after it is done with the foreach loop

Comment: Since you looped through your array it is returning false -> `If the internal pointer points beyond the end of the elements list or the array is empty, current() returns FALSE.` http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php You can verify by using `var_dump(current($movies['Good Movies']['Harry Potter']));`

Comment: Ya, ok thanks, I get it :)